# Tkinter Module Mainloop()

Tags: python

So i have a problem running this code in Pycharm. The name of the file is Python.py
and these are the errors i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabriel/PycharmProjects/Random#1/Python.py", line 30, in <module>
    mainloop()
NameError: name 'mainloop' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *

def main_screen():
    screen = tk.Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    screen.title("Spam Bot 1.0 ")

    # this part is the gui (Graphical user interface)

    # this is the background to be more precise

    bgImage = PhotoImage(file=r"background.png")
    Label(screen, image=bgImage).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    Label(text="Welcome To Spam Bot 1.0", bg="green", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    Button(text="Beemovie Spam ", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()

mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: You need to do `screen.mainloop()`. Mainloop is also a blocking call so should be called last

Comment: Why do you write your GUI as a function is there a reason for ? If the complexity gains in your GUI it will be hard to work this out.

Comment: You need to put your code on the side, only use tab stops or 4 spaces if you're entering a local scope.

Comment: Also note in StackOverflow we don't use a thread to ask multiple questions. Look now on the answer it doesn't fit no more.

Comment: has saying `from tkinter import *` helped?

Comment: have u tried it with IDLE? try copying the files to the IDLE and save elsewhere and try

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `screen.mainloop()`, like this:

```
def main_screen():
    screen = tk.Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x250")
    screen.title("Spam Bot 1.0 ")

    # this part is the gui (Graphical user interface)

    # this is the background to be more precise

    bgImage = PhotoImage(file=r"background.png")
    Label(screen, image=bgImage).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    Label(text="Welcome To Spam Bot 1.0", bg="green", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    Button(text="Beemovie Spam ", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()
    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

The way you did, you call a function defined as `mainloop`, which is clearly not defined. Also please rename `Python.py`, because it can cause name collision, therefore some libraries will not import/work.

Also [joshua-nixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180176/joshua-nixon) mentioned that `mainloop` should be the last thing you call, therefore defining `screen` in that function isn't the best idea. Define it before you call `main_screen`, pass `screen` as a parameter, and do mainloop after the function has finished.

## Edit

```
import tkinter as tk

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.geometry("300x250")
screen.title("Spam Bot 1.0 ")

# this part is the gui (Graphical user interface)

# this is the background to be more precise

bgImage = PhotoImage(file=r"background.png")
Label(screen, image=bgImage).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

tk.Label(text="Welcome To Spam Bot 1.0", bg="green", height="2", width="300").pack()
tk.Label(text="").pack()

tk.Button(text="Beemovie Spam ", height="2", width="300").pack()
tk.Label(text="").pack()
tk.Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()
tk.Label(text="").pack()
tk.Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

With `from tkinter import *`:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("300x250")
screen.title("Spam Bot 1.0 ")

Label(text="Welcome To Spam Bot 1.0", bg="green", height="2", width="300").pack()
Label(text="").pack()

Button(text="Beemovie Spam ", height="2", width="300").pack()
Label(text="").pack()
Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()
Label(text="").pack()
Button(text="Other", height="2", width="300").pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218938/discussion-on-answer-by-nagyl-tkinter-module-mainloop).